# Database name for found

Tags: azure, parse-platform, database-migration, azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to migrate my data from Parse to Azure DocumentDB. I copied the Connection String from the Portal to the Parse DashBoard for migration but I am getting error: 'You need to provide a database name'. What am I doing wrong? 
mongodb://**server**:**password**==@**database_name**.documents.azure.com:**port**/?ssl=true

Comment: Please edit your question to actually show what you entered as a connection string (**WITHOUT your real account name or account key**). Without additional info, we'd only be guessing.

Comment: @DavidMakogon, I have added connection string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that, with DocumentDB, the top-level name (in your example, `database_name`) is the *account name*. Within that account, you have one or more databases. For example, here's my DocumentDB account, with a `Parse` database:

[image]

That database name needs to be added to your connection string. Using your example, it would be added like this:

`mongodb://server:password==@database_name.documents.azure.com:port/parse?ssl=true`

Notice the **/parse** part at the end: That's the *database* within the DocumentDB *account*.

What you're calling `@database_name` in your connection string is, in fact, the DocumentDB *account name*. So really, the proper way to think about it is:

`mongodb://server:password==@docdb_account_name.documents.azure.com:port/docdb_database_name?ssl=true`

Comment: Thanks David. I didn't know I needed to add the db_name to the connection string

Comment: Solid help. I'm porting parse over to MSFTs Parse Hosting solution, it auto generates everything. Nowhere in their docs, nor in Parse's README is this mentioned from what I've seen.